# Best Way To Store User Info separate from User model in django

Tags: python, django

Say I have a bunch of flags/options related to using my app.  Stuff like `firstSetupCompleted`, `tutorialCompleted`, `userExperienceLevel`.

What would be the best way to store these on a per-user basis?  The options I've considered so far are

- django-constance package
- A profile model that's 1-1 with a User model
- a JSON field on the user model

What would the best approach be to storing flags/info related to using the site, but not necessarily directly related to the user themselves (thus do not want to store in the User model)

Comment: I would prefer the second option because, as you say, that is not information that defines the user, but having it as a related model allows us to reach it by extending the user model queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would definitely prefer the second option and go with that. It is because when you do that the linking and reference is easy to maintain and you can get the data of the user with just an extra attribute .